# Connector.open throws IO when using 3g

Tags: java, java-me, 3g, httpconnection

I'm using the [javax microedition Connector](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr218/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html#READ) class to initialise a HttpConnection. This doesn't work with 3g while it works with wifi.

```
HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://www.google.com",Connector.READ);
```

I'm trying to solve this by detecting 3g. Can this be done?

Comment: Does any other application connect to internet using this connection ?

Comment: any other java application can connect using your 3g connection ?

Comment: No only in the emulator/when wifi is enabled on the device it works

Comment: Seems configurational issue with connection at device . probably you need to set the active connection for application saperately ,sony ericsson follow this setting

Comment: Which handset?  Does the phone's web browser work OK when the MIDlet fails?

Comment: @funkybro yes it does. this was tested on a nokia e72